# DNS - delegation - broadcast and network IP adresses

Tags: domain-name-system, delegation

Is it a problem if I delegate network and broadcast addresses as part of network delegation in DNS?

I am following instructions for classless delegation of network on [Zytrax](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch3/) (3.3 Reverse Map Delegation).

In the example from Zytrax (bellow) it's mentioned that all addresses except network and broadcast need to be defined.

```
; definition of our target 192.168.23.64/27 subnet 
; name servers for subnet reverse map
64/27         IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
64/27         IN  NS  ns2.example.com.
; IPs addresses in the subnet - all need to be defined
; except 64 and 95 since they are the subnets
; network and broadcast addresses not hosts/nodes
65            IN  CNAME   65.64/27.23.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA. ;qualified
66            IN  CNAME   66.64/27 ;unqualified name
..
..
```

I understand that I don't have to delegate network and broadcast addresses.

However, if I already have delegations with network and broadcast addresses in my zone files, is it OK to leave them as they are or should I fix it to avoid problems?

Comment: @Zac67 - I will edit the question and remove the classless as it isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegating the network and broadcasting addresses won't serve any purpose but doesn't do any harm either.